# Is Software-Engineering beyond the scope of StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

Are questions specifically about Software Engineering (modelling, requirements gather, etc) off-topic for StackOverflow? [Differences between UML (Unified Modeling Language) Diagrams and DFD (Data Flow Diagrams)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8562465/254477) was closed as off-topic, but it seemed like a good question to me.

It seems to fall under [on-topic criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) :

- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

While it's a bit of a stretch, it's no more so than any other UML question and there a lots of those.

Comment: It's more likely to be on topic on Programmers, although that particular question has lots of problems beyond just scope, such as that it's probably too broad.

Comment: Compare/contrast questions make me heave/purge. (edit) lol I closed that one.

Answer (score 9):

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better site for this kind of question, since it's a [whiteboard](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/) question.  However, note that:

1. "Practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development" is a *restriction, not a permission.*  That a question merely meets this criteria does not guarantee that it is on-topic.
2. "Differences between UML and DFD" is a "List all the Things" question, and is likely to be off-topic everywhere.
3. The mere presence of a relevant tag does not necessarily establish a question's legitimacy, even if there are already many questions already posted under that tag.